# giraph-formats - build jar with dependencies

Tags: maven, hadoop, giraph

I am trying to build giraph-formats jar...with dependencies.. to use it for my project, but even after a successfull built, I am not able to get the jar file.

I have tried to add assembly part to pom, to build jar with dependencies, but it misses few defination for hive, which gives even more difficult errors to resolve. I don't know what is wrong.

I am using **maven 3.04** and **hadoop 0.20.2**

command to run :

```
giraph/trunk/giraph-formats-contrib$ mvn -Phadoop_non_secure verify -Dcheckstyle.skip
```

There are 2 warnings which I am not able to resolve:

---

Results :

```
Tests run: 3, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0

13/01/05 13:42:03 INFO zk.ZooKeeperManager: run: Shutdown hook started.
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-jar-plugin:2.3.2:jar (default-jar) @ giraph-formats-contrib ---
[INFO] Building jar: /home/dipu/Downloads/pradeep/giraph/trunk/giraph-formats-contrib/target/giraph-formats-contrib-0.2-SNAPSHOT.jar
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-jar-plugin:2.3.2:test-jar (default) @ giraph-formats-contrib ---
[INFO] Building jar: /home/dipu/Downloads/pradeep/giraph/trunk/giraph-formats-contrib/target/giraph-formats-contrib-0.2-SNAPSHOT-tests.jar
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-checkstyle-plugin:2.9:check (default) @ giraph-formats-contrib ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] >>> findbugs-maven-plugin:2.5.1:check (default) @ giraph-formats-contrib >>>
[WARNING] Failure to transfer asm:asm/maven-metadata.xml from file:../../local.repository/trunk was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of local.repository has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer metadata asm:asm/maven-metadata.xml from/to local.repository (file:../../local.repository/trunk): No connector available to access repository local.repository (file:../../local.repository/trunk) of type legacy using the available factories WagonRepositoryConnectorFactory
[WARNING] Failure to transfer asm:asm/maven-metadata.xml from file:../../local.repository/trunk was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of local.repository has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer metadata asm:asm/maven-metadata.xml from/to local.repository (file:../../local.repository/trunk): No connector available to access repository local.repository (file:../../local.repository/trunk) of type legacy using the available factories WagonRepositoryConnectorFactory
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- findbugs-maven-plugin:2.5.1:findbugs (findbugs) @ giraph-formats-contrib ---
[INFO] Fork Value is true
     [java] The following classes needed for analysis were missing:
     [java]   org.apache.hadoop.security.token.Token
     [java]   org.apache.hadoop.security.Credentials
     [java] Missing classes: 1
[INFO] Done FindBugs Analysis....
[INFO] 
[INFO] <<< findbugs-maven-plugin:2.5.1:check (default) @ giraph-formats-contrib <<<
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- findbugs-maven-plugin:2.5.1:check (default) @ giraph-formats-contrib ---
[INFO] BugInstance size is 0
[INFO] Error size is 0
[INFO] No errors/warnings found
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1:27.588s
[INFO] Finished at: Sat Jan 05 13:42:38 IST 2013
[INFO] Final Memory: 39M/186M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

---

**default pom for giraph formats I have pasted below.....**

---

```
<!--
Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one
or more contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file
distributed with this work for additional information
regarding copyright ownership.  The ASF licenses this file
to you under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the
"License"); you may not use this file except in compliance
with the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at

http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing,
software distributed under the License is distributed on an
"AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY
KIND, either express or implied.  See the License for the
specific language governing permissions and limitations
under the License.
-->

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <parent>
    <groupId>org.apache.giraph</groupId>
    <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
    <version>0.2-SNAPSHOT</version>
  </parent>
  <artifactId>giraph-formats-contrib</artifactId>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>Apache Giraph Formats</name>

  <properties>
    <top.dir>${project.basedir}/..</top.dir>
    <lib.dir>${top.dir}/lib</lib.dir>
  </properties>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.9</version>
        <configuration>
          <configLocation>${top.dir}/checkstyle.xml</configLocation>
          <headerLocation>${top.dir}/license-header.txt</headerLocation>
          <enableRulesSummary>false</enableRulesSummary>
          <failOnError>true</failOnError>
          <includeTestSourceDirectory>false</includeTestSourceDirectory>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <phase>verify</phase>
            <goals>
               <goal>check</goal>
             </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
        <configuration>
          <systemProperties>
            <property>
              <name>prop.jarLocation</name>
              <value>${top.dir}/giraph/target/giraph-${project.version}-${forHadoop}-jar-with-dependencies.jar</value>
            </property>
          </systemProperties>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>findbugs-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <xmlOutput>true</xmlOutput>
          <findbugsXmlOutput>false</findbugsXmlOutput>
          <excludeFilterFile>${top.dir}/findbugs-exclude.xml</excludeFilterFile>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <phase>verify</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>check</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>

  <repositories>
    <!-- This is the main maven repository. Normally we wouldn't need to put
       it here when it's the only one being used, but since we need to add
       special repositories to get hcatalog we need to mention this one
       specifically otherwise it won't be included. -->
    <repository>
      <id>central</id>
      <name>Maven Repository</name>
      <url>http://repo1.maven.org/maven2</url>
      <releases>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
      </releases>
    </repository>
    <!-- This is necessary for hcatalog. -->
    <repository>
      <id>apache</id>
      <name>Apache Repository</name>
      <url>https://repository.apache.org/content/repositories/snapshots</url>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
      </snapshots>
    </repository>
    <!-- This is necessary for hive-metastore dependencies for hcatalog. -->
    <repository>
      <id>datanucleus</id>
      <name>datanucleus maven repository</name>
      <url>http://www.datanucleus.org/downloads/maven2</url>
      <layout>default</layout>
      <releases>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <checksumPolicy>warn</checksumPolicy>
      </releases>
    </repository>
  </repositories>

  <profiles>
    <profile>
      <id>hadoop_0.20.203</id>
      <activation>
        <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
      </activation>
      <dependencies>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
          <artifactId>hadoop-test</artifactId>
          <version>${hadoop.version}</version>
          <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
      </dependencies>
    </profile>

    <profile>
      <id>hadoop_1.0</id>
      <dependencies>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
          <artifactId>hadoop-test</artifactId>
          <version>${hadoop.version}</version>
          <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
      </dependencies>
    </profile>

    <profile>
      <id>hadoop_non_secure</id>
      <dependencies>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
          <artifactId>hadoop-test</artifactId>
          <version>${hadoop.version}</version>
          <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
      </dependencies>
    </profile>

    <profile>
      <id>hadoop_facebook</id>
      <dependencies>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
          <artifactId>hadoop-test</artifactId>
          <version>${hadoop.version}</version>
          <scope>system</scope>
          <systemPath>${lib.dir}/facebook-hadoop-0.20-test.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>
      </dependencies>
    </profile>
  </profiles>

  <dependencies>
    <!-- compile dependencies. sorted lexicographically. -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-cli</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-cli</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.giraph</groupId>
      <artifactId>giraph</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.hbase</groupId>
      <artifactId>hbase</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.hcatalog</groupId>
      <artifactId>hcatalog-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.hive</groupId>
      <artifactId>hive-common</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.hive</groupId>
      <artifactId>hive-exec</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.hive</groupId>
      <artifactId>hive-metastore</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.zookeeper</groupId>
      <artifactId>zookeeper</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.giraph</groupId>
      <artifactId>giraph</artifactId>
      <version>0.2-SNAPSHOT</version>
      <type>test-jar</type>
    </dependency>

    <!-- provided dependencies. sorted lexicographically. -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.accumulo</groupId>
      <artifactId>accumulo-core</artifactId>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- test dependencies. sorted lexicographically. -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.hbase</groupId>
      <artifactId>hbase</artifactId>
      <type>test-jar</type>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

Those warnings look harmless. If you're concerned, you should just delete the cached files that it is warning about, and let it download them again.